# WI-FI and Bluetooth got "hardblocked" after upgrading xubuntu from 22.04 to 22.10

Tags: xubuntu, bluetooth, 22.10

I have been using xubuntu for sometime now, and I've upgraded it every 6 months when a new upgrade is available. There's always an issue to solve everytime, and this time is that all of the sudden, I can't seem to be able to enable wifi or bluetooth.

I have a VAIO laptop and the physical button to enable or disable wifi and bluetooth is ON. I have switched it on and off several times and the problem persists.

This is the output for rfkill list alL.

`rfkill list all 0: sony-wifi: Wireless LAN Soft blocked: no Hard blocked: yes 1: sony-bluetooth: Bluetooth Soft blocked: no Hard blocked: yes 2: phy0: Wireless LAN Soft blocked: no Hard blocked: no 3: hci0: Bluetooth Soft blocked: no Hard blocked: no`

I have tried some solutions such as removing the battery, and doing this:

```
echo "blacklist iwlwifi" >> sudo /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf.

echo "blacklist sony_laptop" >> sudo /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

but the problem persists.

Comment: Do you have the kernel from previous Ubuntu release (22.04) on your system? if so try to boot it.

Comment: Boot a 22.04 ISO and see if it is blocked

Comment: @nobody I don't know. This is the uname -r output: 5.19.0-23-generic. It have no idea if it is the previous or current one. That's the one I have...

Comment: @Jeremy31 thank you but I'm unable to do that at the moment.

Comment: @JoséRojas do you have access to grub-menu?

Comment: `sudo apt install acpid` if you can. Then run `acpi_listen` in terminal and try a combo with one of the Fn keys`  This is only a function test.

Comment: There is no Fn key combination to enable or disable wifi in this laptop; there's a physical button that has always been on. I have switched it on and off just to try but there's no change. when it's off, the network and bluetooth icons disappear from the panel, and they reappear then I switch the button back on; but it continues to be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it suddenly started to work again. I mean, I don't really know what exactly happened as every time I attempted a solution, I would reboot and nothing changed. But then, I turned off the computer and went off to sleep.

Today, when I turned it on again, the wifi was working normally, to my pleasant surprise. Nonetheless, the bluetooth continued to appeared as "disabled".

Thinking of connecting my speaker via bluetooth to my phone, I turned the speaker on and it got connected... to my laptop!

So, it is actually working, but it has to be connected to a device. When disconnected, the wifi icon is grayed out and shows the "bluetooth disabled" message, instead of remaining ON but disconnected, as before.

EDIT: I continue to get this message when I click on the bluetooth icon on the panel, even though it is active and connected.

[image]

Comment: And, then, it suddenly stopped working again... ???

Comment: And, then, it suddenly stopped working again... ??? After having being working all day, I turned it off at night and today when I turn it on, there's no WiFi! Again! And I have restarted it several times all ready. What could this be? Also, as for the Bluetooth, it connects to the devices but I can't open the Bluetooth manager because it says it's off, and neither can I send files from the laptop because I get the same message that Bluetooth needs to be enabled before but it is connected to the speaker and I can connect my phone too. But send files

Comment: Still not working...

Comment: As of today, I turned on my laptop again and both Bluetooth and Wifi appear as enabled and are working. I fear that if I reboot it, it would again show as disabled and won't work. `rfkill
ID TYPE      DEVICE              SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan      sony-wifi      unblocked unblocked
 1 bluetooth sony-bluetooth unblocked unblocked
 2 bluetooth hci0           unblocked unblocked
 3 wlan      phy0           unblocked unblocked`